# Проверка на существование div js

Tags: javascript

Как проверить правильно на существование дива?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // тайтлы

  var elemForTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("field-name-field-season");

  if (elemForTitle.length > 0) {
    elemForTitle[0].title += "Время использования изделия: зима, лето или круглый год";
    elemForTitle[0].className += " titleshowcl";
  }
  var elemForTitleS1 = document.getElementsByClassName("field-name-field-weight");
  var elemForTitleS2 = document.getElementsByClassName("field-name-field-length");
  var elemForTitleS3 = document.getElementsByClassName("field-name-field-shirina");
  var elemForTitleS4 = document.getElementsByClassName("field-name-field-visota");
  var elemForTitleS5 = document.getElementsByClassName("field-name-field-crew");

  if (elemForTitleS1.length > 0) {
    elemForTitleS1[0].title += " Вес изделия";
    elemForTitleS1[0].className += " titleshowcl";
  }

  if (elemForTitleS2.length > 0) {
    elemForTitleS2[0].title += " Длина изделия";
    elemForTitleS2[0].className += " titleshowcl";
  }

  if (elemForTitleS3.length > 0) {
    elemForTitleS3[0].title += " Ширина изделия";
    elemForTitleS3[0].className += " titleshowcl";
  }

  if (elemForTitleS4.length > 0) {
    elemForTitleS4[0].title += " Высота изделия";
    elemForTitleS4[0].className += " titleshowcl";
  }

  if (elemForTitleS5.length > 0) {
    elemForTitleS5[0].title += " Вместимость изделия, человек";
    elemForTitleS5[0].className += " titleshowcl";
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="group-spec field-group-div">
  <div class="field field-name-field-weight field-type-number-integer field-label-inline clearfix">
    <div class="field-label">Вес:&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even">24 кг</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-field-length field-type-number-integer field-label-inline clearfix">
    <div class="field-label">Длина:&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even">550 см.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field-name-field-crew field-type-range-integer field-label-inline clearfix">
    <div class="field-label">Экипаж:&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even">2&ndash;3 чел.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if (elemForTitle.length === 0) {`, поскольку getElementsByClassName всегда возвращает массив, и никогда - null.

Comment: @Yaant, строго говоря не массив - а Live-collection

Comment: @Grundy, да, уже хотел сам исправить свой комментарий, но не успел. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) возвращает коллекцию. Поэтому чтобы проверить есть ли в ней что-то или нет, нужно проверить свойство `length`

свойство `length` показывает сколько элементов находится в коллекции. Если в коллекции нет элементов - значение будет 0, если есть хотя бы 1 - не 0.

Comment: сменил код elemForTitle.length === 0 - та же сказка ((

Comment: @ИгорьФостяк, ну так очевидно, если length==0 То элементов в коллекции нет.

Comment: @ИгорьФостяк, обновил ответ

Comment: понял. синтаксис хромает у меня. != вот так или >0  нужно ставить

Comment: @ИгорьФостяк, именно!

Comment: спасибо! А также Yaant . я помаленьку превращаюсь из Homo javascript neanderthalensis в Homo javascript  sapiens ))

Comment: @ИгорьФостяк Я, кстати, действительно, стормозил в своем комментарии, проверять-то длину и правда в данном случае надо не на равенство нулю, а наоборот, на неравенство. :)